# how to stay on the same page on clicking a link

Tags: routes, navigation

I need to know how to stay on the same page when a link is clicked. If `l()`, what can be passed as the second argument for the link to be for the page currently visualized?

I need to override `l()` for menu slot titles inside the megamenus module so that they don't redirect to a different page. Is there any token in Drupal 7 which stores the URL of the current page being displayed?

Comment: cant do with another tool?

Answer (score 1):

Try hash # char...

```
l(t('test'), '#');
```

Comment: Resolves as: `<a href="/%23">test</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also.

```
<?php
  l(t('Link text'), 'javascript:void(0);');
?>
```

Comment: Resolves as: `<a href="/javascript%3Avoid%280%29%3B">Link text</a>`

Comment: @Clive any way to make it exactly `<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link text</a>` ?

Comment: If you think about it, you might aswell add this with JS as it wouldnt work without it anyway.